# MySQL Group by UserID only show last post?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show a list with the last posts from each user. If I group by ID however I get the first post instead of the last. How can I group by UID and show only the row with the biggest `Date`?

This is what I'm trying now:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts GROUP BY `UID` ORDER BY `Date` DESC
```

Comment: This query should be returning the whole table, pretty much... Are you sure you are even getting the oldest post from each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want the largest `Date` per user, you can use MySQL's `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(`Date`), * FROM Posts GROUP BY `UID`
```

You can also specify it in the `HAVING` clause too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts
GROUP BY `UID`
HAVING `Date` = MAX(`Date`)
ORDER BY `Date` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a join, to get the max date, and then only choosing those records:

```
select p.*
from posts p join
     (select uid, max(date) as maxdate
      from posts p
      group by uid
     ) pmax
     on p.uid = pmax.uid and
        p.date = pmax.maxdate
```